# What are the major security differences between jemalloc and mozjemalloc?

Tags: firefox, memory

In a [rather heated mailing list thread](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2019-August/013982.html), I read some information provided by one of the developers of mozjemalloc, the memory allocator in Firefox that was forked from jemalloc, that stated that the fork has significant security improvements over [regular](https://news.sophos.com/en-us/2019/04/18/protected-cve-2018-18500-heap-write-after-free-in-firefox-analysis-and-exploitation/) [insecure](http://phrack.org/issues/68/10.html#article) [jemalloc](http://phrack.org/issues/69/14.html#article). I've been out-of-the-loop on browser security for several years now. What are the major security differences between the two?

I am curious about both the memory corruption mitigations present in one but not in the other, as well as general design designs that makes one or the other more or less resilient to attack.

The source code: https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/memory/build/mozjemalloc.cpp